# A way to distinguish between interleaved output from two background processes

Tags: bash, shell, job-control

If I have two backgrounded processes that produce input to STDOUT or STDERR (e.g., two installation scripts), is there an easy way to make these two output streams distinguishable? I guess I can pipe each processes's output through a sed program that prefixes every line of each output with a different tag, but I'm looking for something easier.

Comment: Why do not use 1>file 2>&1 and use different files for each process?

Comment: Pipe the output (stdout and stderr) to `logger -t {progname}` perhaps?

Comment: How about using a terminal multiplexer like GNU screen or tmux?

Comment: I guess your processes produce output instead of input. IMHO you will not find anything easier that `sed` or other filter. If you want the mixed output in one terminal window then some filtering with sed is quite easy. You can do something like `program1 2>&1 | sed -e 's/^/P1 /' &`.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be to start each of the two background jobs and redirect their output to files:

```
 utility1 >utility1.out 2>utility1.err &
 utility2 >utility2.out 2>utility2.err &
```

This has the added benefit of not clogging up your terminal with output.

You may obviously redirect both the error and output streams to the same file too:

```
 utility1 >utility1.out 2>&1 &
 utility2 >utility2.out 2>&1 &
```

You could also use `tmux`:

```
 tmux new "utility1" ';' split "utility2"
```

`tmux` will exit as soon as all commands have exited. To avoid that, change `"utility"` to `"utility;read"`. This will make the pane stay open until you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.